Only show legend items inside linked maps for layers
My QGIS project is linked to a WMS geological map service. My legend looks like this:

As you can see, all the lithologies are listed under the "Detailed Surface Geology" layer. The problem is, when I click the "Only show items in linked maps" checkbox, it only seems to filter out the actual layers which aren't in the map. It does not filter out the subgroups within this layer.
How can I get around this?
